# How do you change theme variable value in Nebular UI?

Tags: angular, nebular

Supposed that i want to change `nb-layout-header` height,
Nebular Documentation shows that variable name for header height is `header-height`

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/layout/theme#nblayoutheadercomponent

how do i modify the variable value? do i have to create a custom theme for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked Nebular UI documentation and to change the header height, you can go to the `themes.scss` and define the `header-height` there.

I've tried it on the Nebular sample [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/akveo/nebular-seed)

```
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default';

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  header-height: 3rem
), default, default);
```

The changing of the Nebular UI CSS Component reference [here](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/enable-css-properties-mode#enable-css-custom-properties-mode)

Comment: aah, i see, i didn't read the docs well enough,
thank you for pointing out